# Archived mail keeps reappearing in Inbox on OS X

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have a problem with Mail in OS X El Capitan (10.11.5).
If I archive messages from my Inbox, go to another folder, then back to my Inbox, the messages are there again.
Quitting mail and starting it again doesn't solve this..
I rebuilt the mail database by deleting the Envelope Index files from /Users//Library/Mail/V3/MailData/, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Richard

ps I know there's a comparable thread on this forum, but it's specifically about Mail on the iPhone and Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

> Archived mail keeps reappearing in Inbox …

Smells of a database inconsistency.

> I rebuilt the mail database by deleting the Envelope Index files from /Users//Library/Mail/V3/MailData/

Critically:

- did you quit Mail – **and allow time** for completion of that quit – before those deletions?

Some of the many articles about *Envelope Index* lack that recommendation. Here's one of the better articles: [SpamSieve Manual: How can I rebuild Apple Mail’s database?](http://c-command.com/spamsieve/help/how-can-i-rebuild-apple)

**Cross reference**

My [reply to a MacRumors Forums topic](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/those-of-you-who-use-mail-with-gmail-how-the-hell-do-you-do-it.1982433/#post-23132286) that appears to involve a database inconsistency.